# Removing full rows when only cells are highlighted

Tags: excel, vba

I've selected let say a box of 4 cells.

How to remove full rows of that box of selected cells?

Answer (score 1):

It is sufficient to use the default selector.

```
Selection.EntireRow.Delete
```

Answer (score 0):

Change range and try:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()

    Dim i As Long
    Dim rng As Range

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        Set rng = .Range("A10:D20")

        For i = rng.Row + rng.Rows.Count - 1 To rng.Row Step -1
           Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
        Next

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: This will skip rows as the delete will move all the data up one reference. ie. you delete row 1, row 2 moves into row 1 but now you delete row 2, which holds the data that was in row 3... row 2 (now in row 1 is skipped)

Comment: @sten your are absolutely right, when clock is ticking mistakes happen. i correct the code using "For each loop" starting from the end.